# OSX - error generating final archive: Unable to get debug signature key

Tags: java, android, macos

I recently installed the android sdk and created my first app.  When I try to run my project I get this error "Error generating final archive: Unable to get debug signature key".  I've looked for my ~/.android folder using the terminal command ls -a but the folder doesn't exist.  Any ideas why the ~/.android folder would be missing?

Answer (score -1):

In the terminal, try typing "cd ~/.android". Then, "open ." and your Finder will hopefully find it.